# Laravel model - add custom field based on value of other column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have a laravel model here with 5 columns. Id_profile, first_name, last_name, dbo, and **gender**. **Gender is a int on database**. It receives 0, 1 or 2.

**0 is to Male**

**1 is to Female**

**2 is to Other**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Enums\GenderEnum;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'profile';
    protected $fillable = ['id_profile', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dbo', 'gender'];
    protected $appends = ['gender_name'];

    protected $dates = ['dbo'];
    protected $casts = ['dbo'  => 'datetime:d/m/Y'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_profile';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getGenderNameAttribute($gender)
    {
        switch ($gender) {
            case '0':
                return 'Male';
            case '1':
                return 'Female';
            case '2':
                return 'Other';
        }
    }

}
```

I wanna return on model the gender number and the new field gender_name with the description of its.

I don't know how I can parameterize a function to do that. I tried it with the appends variable and getGenderNameAttribute function.

How can I add the gender_name to model result?

Comment: use `switch ($this->gender) {` and not the variable `$gender`. that variable name should be `$value` as it is the value of the attribute `gender_name` if it existed in the database (null in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use laravel 8 and you are defining an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and if your column is really `gender` only, you need to change the value:

```
public function getGenderNameAttribute($value)
{
    switch ($this->attributes['gender']) {
        case 0: // here is number not string.
            return 'Male';
        case 1:
            return 'Female';
        case 2:
            return 'Other';
    }
}
```

By this accessor now you have the attribute `gender_name`, you can access your model with:

```
$profile = Profile::find(1);
echo $profile->gender_name; // Male
echo $profile->gender; //0
```